# API: Fetch cloud storage S3

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

cannot **Fetch Cloud Object Storage S3**, I tried the calls

```
https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage
https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHubNetworkStorage
```

but all the network storages and Cloud Storage SWIFT S3 are fetched. is there any other api call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only Cloud Object Storage S3, you need to use a filter, try the following request please:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHubNetworkStorage?objectFilter={"hubNetworkStorage":{"serviceResourceName":{"operation":"*=Cleversafe"}}}

Method: Get
```

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Account::getHubNetworkStorage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHubNetworkStorage)
- [Object Filters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters)